# jQuery animate border color on hover?

Tags: jquery

Using a [color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) to animate background color on hover.

```
$(function() {
    $('.listing-2 li a').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor: "#0e7796"
        }, 'fast');
    });
    $('.listing-2 li a').mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            backgroundColor: "#d6f2c5"
        }, 'fast');
    });
});
```

How can I do the same for border color?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery animate backgroundColor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

Comment: Make sure you load jQueryUI's [color plugin](http://jqueryui.com/animate/) first

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Found in google

```
    $('.listing-2 li a').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ borderTopColor: "#0e7796" }, 'fast');
});
$('.listing-2 li a').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({ borderTopColor: "#fff" }, 'fast');
});
```

it must be a "borderTopColor" (or left, right, bottom) instead of "borderColor".

Answer (score 14):

To animate the color of the entire border use:

```
$(this).animate({ borderTopColor: '#59b4de', borderLeftColor: '#59b4de', borderRightColor: '#59b4de', borderBottomColor: '#59b4de' }, 'fast');
```

Apparently, you need to specify them all.

Comment: What does this setup offer more than setting up the entire "border-color" to animate? (see @michael's answer above) Is this setup is more browser compliant?

Comment: I am not sure if this is still the same in the current version on jQuery, but when I answered the question you had to specify all of them, you could not animate borderColor as a whole. I dunno why.

Answer (score 5):

this works also.

```
$("div.item").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"border-color": "#999999"}, "slow");
},
function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"border-color": "#BFBFBF"}, "slow");
});
```

Comment: How to use your code if div.item creates after dom generated?

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue. I apparently didn't have the jQuery-UI file attached to my document. Once I attached it. Everything works perfectly with "C. Spencer Beggs" answer.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery animate only accept numeric values. See [docs]: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

You may use jQuery.Color plugin or use jQuery UI which extends animate and lets you use non-numeric values in animate.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the jQuery solutions, you can animate the border color with CSS transitions as well.  Since you're animating the `background-color` with `fast`, you'd want to use a `200ms` transition.

**Your Case**

```
.listing-2 li {
    border:1px solid #d6f2c5;
    transition: border 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.listing-2 li a:hover {
    border:1px solid #0e7796;
}
```

**Generic Example**

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #d6f2c5;
  transition: border 200ms ease-in-out;
}
.container:hover {
  border: 1px solid #0e7796;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score -5):

You could try this:

```
$(this).animate({border: "3px solid #FFF55B"}, 100);
```