# Is there a better way of achieving this effect?

Tags: jquery, border

I have an image thumbnail with a light colored border which, on mouseover, I want to crossfade to a dark colored border. I'm thinking that the easiest way to achieve this would be to fade in a second div with a darker border over the existing one.

Is there a better or different way to fade in a border color change?

Thanks.

Comment: The border isn't part of the image by the way. The border is part of the DIV that is enclosing the image.

Comment: see this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813493/jquery-animate-border-color-on-hover][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813493/jquery-animate-border-color-on-hover

Comment: create a new class with the darker border and fade to the class. :)

Comment: Have you had a look whether jQuery UI supports fading the border colour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load the **jQuery UI** into your page. Included with the core package (if I'm not mistaken; you may need to customize your download package) is the ability to use jQuery's `.animate()` on color values (and/or transitions between two CSS classes). This is something absent from the core jQuery library out-of-the-box.

With that, you can just do something as menial as the following:

```
// e.g. assuming #foo has default border-color #999999
$('#foo').on('mouseover', function () {
    $(this).animate({
        borderColor : "#333333"
    });
});
```

Modify according to your interests.

#### EDIT

The easiest way to implement this would be to leverage CSS itself, and just use jQuery to toggle between CSS rules.

```
#foo { border-color:#999; }
#foo.hovering { border-color:#333; }
```

Then you can just transition using jQuery UI's extended jQuery functions:

```
$('#foo').hover(
    function () {
        // this is on mouseover
        $(this).addClass('hovering', 'fast');
    },
    function () {
        // this is on mouseout
        $(this).removeClass('hovering', 'fast');
    }
);
```

Comment: +1 for interesting use of animate, only cause I never thought of that myself :-D

Comment: I would use .bind instead of .on though so I could trigger the mouseover, mouseout accordingly..

Comment: @chris ~ why? `.on` is intended (and recommended by the jQuery team) to be used in lieu of **both** `.bind` and `.delegate`, and is part of the move to deprecate `.live`. Unless I'm mistaken, you **can** trigger off of `.on` hooks.

Comment: Works nicely. What would be the easiest way of adding a mouseout event to reverse back to the original border color specified in the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways.

One is through CSS3 transitions. Although not working in IE, you can have it progressively enhanced to modern browsers.

assuming your div has a class of `imageBorder`:

```
div.imageborder {border-color: #FFFFFF;}
div.imageBorder:hover {
    border-color: #FF0000;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

The other way is to use javascript, Here is a jQuery sample:

```
$('div.imageBorder').hover(
    function(){
      $(this).animate({
        border-color: '#FF0000',
        },200,function(){});
    },
    function(){
       $(this).animate({
        border-color: '#FFFFFF',
        },200,function(){});
    }
);
```

This will work in IE as well, but at the cost of loading an extra library.

Answer (score 0):

Put your thumbnail inside a DIV with light colored border (default), later on mouseover find the div and change the style (border-width and border-color), although it is not a fadding style but as user quickly mouseover and mouseout on the image looks like minor fadding effect that is enough i guess. Write your own javascript code to make it faster (jQuery surely gets more time javascript code) .

Answer (score 0):

Can you apply a CSS3 transition on the border color?