# jQuery UI Highlight Effect - how can I use the border?

Tags: jquery, css

I try to use highlight in jQuery but color works but border doesn't work.
How can I use the border? `border: 2px solid #32a511`

```
$("div").click(function () {
      $(this).effect("highlight", {
color: '#effdeb', border: '2px solid #32a511'}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813493/jquery-animate-border-color-on-hover

Comment: Thank you for comment but I would like to use border with color. I use only color it works but not with border.

Comment: It is not exclusive, you can still use both, just replace the "border" argument with the ones from the other question.

Comment: I'd tried to do it but it doesn't work. Could you give me a example? I can better understand it. Thanks,

Comment: I don't think jQuery accepts 'border' as an argument for the highlight effect.  See: [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/effect-highlight.htm) and [here](http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.7/docs/effect-highlight.html#demo)

Comment: I read all doc but I couldn't t find a solution. Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the jQuery `.effect()` simply applies pre-made animations to your element. as per Daniel's comment, it seems that the highlight effect does not work on borders.

instead, you could use the jQuery `.animate()` to animate your div manually:

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    "background-color": '#effdeb',
    "border-color": "32a511",
    "border-width": "2px"
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```