# jQuery: animate text color for input field?

Tags: jquery, input, colors, jquery-animate

I've got this really simple piece of code that I thought was the correct way to get jQuery to animate the text color for a given input field.

```
$('input').animate({color: '#f00'}, 500);
```

But it won't work. However, I can change the text color:

```
$('input').css('color', '#f00');
```

I've tried this in both Safari 4 and Firefox 3.5 with the same (lacking) results.
I'd really appreciate any input on this problem as I'm running out of hair... Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery animate backgroundColor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

jQuery doesn't support color animations so you'll need the [color](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) plugin or, [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/). Both allow you to use the syntax you're using for properties like background-color and color.

Answer (score 2):

To animate color you need the [jquery color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without the color plugin. I've answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694295/jquery-background-color-animate-not-working/5718151#5718151).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need [Color Animations plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) for this

Comment: And you can learn about this on the first page of google search http://www.google.ru/search?q=jquery+animate+color

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQueryUI](http://docs.jquery.com/UI) and your code works as it is.

Comment: Including jQuery-ui is a hefty include just for a color animation!

Answer (score 0):

I found the color plugin to be extremely flaky from one page load to another, even on a static page with the exact same code..! ColorBlend did the job perfectly time though.
http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.colorBlend.js_6.txt