# jquery random color hover

Tags: jquery, colors, hover

I'm using [jquery color](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) to generate some random colors. Id like these colors to appear when the user hovers over any radio button labels.

Following the example on [this site](http://buildinternet.com/2009/09/its-a-rainbow-color-changing-text-and-backgrounds/), i thought i might try:

```
spectrum();

function spectrum(){

var hue = ('lots of stuff here that generates random hue -- code on example webpage')

$('label').hover(function() {
   $(this).animate( { color: hue }, 10000) });

spectrum(); 

}
```

My hover selector isn't working and everything is staying its default color. I'm obviously bungling this somehow, but I'm not experienced enough to understand what's going wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your HTML & CSS. There isn't enough code here to know what's going wrong.

Comment: what do u need? there's no css except what's from the body. and the html is just a bunch of input tags.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('label').hover(function() {
        var hue = 'rgb('
            + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ','
            + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ','
            + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
       $(this).stop().animate( { color: hue }, 500);
    },function() {
       $(this).stop().animate( { color: '#000' }, 500);
    });
});
```

Also see my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YD7Sb/1/).

=== UPDATE ===

```
function startAnimation(o) {
    var hue = 'rgb('
        + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ','
        + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ','
        + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
    $(o.currentTarget).animate( { color: hue }, 500, function() {
        startAnimation(o);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('label').hover(
        startAnimation,
        function() {
            $(this).stop().animate( { color: '#000' }, 500);
        }
    );
});
```

See my updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YD7Sb/4/).

Comment: so this is really close to what i want to achieve. but instead of being random over every hover -- i want the color to change randomly while hovered.
so for example: if a color changes every second and i hover for three seconds, the user should see three colors....hmm i wonder what happens if i take out the stops

Comment: ah, okay. so the jquery color plugin calls in a function that 'transitions' one color into another. and to keep changing colors, it recursively calls itself. i dropped this script into there and it works! but theres still something wrong becuase it requires a lot of processing power and the website stalls everytime I hover

Comment: yea!! could u walk me through what ure code is doing? what does it mean for startAnimation to pass "o" down?

Comment: The jquery [hover method](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) passes an `event object` to the handler _startAnimation_. It's needed to select the current target.

Comment: I find that adding `queue: false` to the animation options runs much faster than calling `stop()` and then `animate()` again, e.g. $(this).animate( { color: '#000', queue: false }, 500);

Answer (score 0):

The main problem that jQuery doesn't support the color animation. More results can be found [jQuery: animate text color for input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354277/jquery-animate-text-color-for-input-field)

Comment: I don't think he's having troubles generating a random color. It's APPLYING that color with the jquery.color plugin that is giving him trouble.

Answer (score 0):

`$('label').hover` will add a mouseover/mouseout event to the label. You are doing this infinitely as, you are calling spectrum over and over again.
Try this instead.

```
$('label').hover(function() {
    (function anim() {
        var hue = //hue stuff
        $(this).animate({
            color: hue
        }, 10000, function() {
            anim();
        });
    })();
}, function() {
    $( this ).animate({
         color: //original color
    }, 1000);
});
```