# PHP-Code called every time link is hovered?

Tags: php, html, css

I've got a css/html menu, now I want to execute this PHP-Script every time the button is hovered by the user:

CSS:

```
background: <?php printf( "#%06X\n", mt_rand( 0, 0xFFFFFF )); ?>;
```

This is in my css. It's getting correctly called when I reload the page, but the color stays the same even if I hover the button... How can I change this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This can't be done in PHP. Javascript is what you are looking for.

Comment: PHP only executes once on the server side before the HTML is delivered to the client. Anythong on the client-side needs to be done using JS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP is only executed once on the server.

You can reproduce what you want with Javascript (preferably jQuery).

See this answer. [jquery random color hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379353/jquery-random-color-hover)

Comment: Prefereably jQuery?  That seems like an odd value judgement.  Doesn't seem to be worth downloading an entire framework (especially one as large as jQuery) to simply change the background color on a page.

Comment: True, but no one else answered with a pure javascript solution. hint. hint.