# jQuery: animate text color

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, jquery-animate

i wanna dynamically change the link color within a hover event. I got the following code so far but it doesn´t work. Any suggestions why? In my oppinion it seems to be right...

```
    $('.fadelink').hover(function(){            
        $(this).animate({
            color: '#333'
        }, 600);            
    },
    function(){
        $(this).animate({
            color: '#999'
        }, 600);          
    });
```

Comment: if you dont want to go too complicated, simply fade the element out, change the colour and fade it back in. simplest option.

Comment: try this http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: animate text color for input field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354277/jquery-animate-text-color-for-input-field)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add [colors](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin to make it work. That is stripped from core.

Comment: Yup, forgot about the color plugin. My mistake.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery doesn't support animation of colors, but it can with the color plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

However, there's another route you could take, with CSS3, if you don't mind it not working in some older browsers:

```
.baseClass {
    color:#999; 

    -webkit-transition-property:color; 
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s, 1s; 
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
}

.baseClass:hover {
    color: #333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to this question: [jQuery: animate text color for input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354277/jquery-animate-text-color-for-input-field)

You **cannot** animate css text color with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [jQuery color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) to make color animation work.