# How can I animate text colors using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.nav_menu')
        .css( {backgroundPosition: "0 0"} )
        .mouseover(function(){
            $(this).animate({
            backgroundPosition:"(-650px 0)",
            'color': '#000000'
        }, {duration:700})
        })
        .mouseout(function(){
            $(this).animate({backgroundPosition:"(0px 0)"}, {duration:900, complete:function(){
                $(this).css({backgroundPosition: "0 0"})
            }})
        })
});
```

What is wrong with this? The text color doesn't change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery animate backgroundColor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to either use [jQuery UI effects](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects) or the [color animation](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) plugin to animate colors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) plugin to animate colours.

Comment: Tell us what "this" is. When providing answers, imagine links don't exist.