# Jquery, animate background colour?

Tags: jquery

is it possible to animate the background colour of an element in jquery without using any plugins?

Maybe something other than animate would be better? The effect I'm going for is for the background colour of an element to animate to another colour, and then back to the original colour.

How would I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate, asked several times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should really use the [jquery color](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) plugin. What's the issue with using plugins?

Comment: No issue really, just trying to use minimal files :) Thanks for your response.