# why i can't change the 'div''s background color to 'yellow'

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

```
$('div').animate({ 'background':'yellow' }, 2000,'linear', function() {
        })
```

why??

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From jQuery API (http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All animated properties should be
>   numeric (except as noted below);
>   properties that are non-numeric cannot
>   be animated using basic jQuery
>   functionality. (For example, width,
>   height, or left can be animated **but
>   background-color cannot be**.) Property
>   values are treated as a number of
>   pixels unless otherwise specified. The
>   units em and % can be specified where
>   applicable.

To animate color use jQuery.color plugin: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

Answer (score 0):

In order to animate colors, you must include [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [jQuery color animations](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) plugin.