# I want to use .animate colors when triggered using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to use .animate to change colors when `.bind('click')`is fired, using jquery

```
$('#selector').animate({width:'2.5%'},'slow').css('background-color','#F2F2F2');

<style>
#selector{
background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
</style>
```

Thanks
Jean

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery animate backgroundColor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the color plugin

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color