# How to change div background softly on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was searching for a way to change the background of the body of the page when the user hovered a specific link on a page (I was planning to change the background to a different color depending on the link hovered), but i was intending to make this effect works softly, just like the **transition** effect in CSS.
Is there any way to do it? Using JS or even CSS?

For the hover effect i would use the JQuery's hover function, but I can't find any way for the softly transition stuff.

Comment: I've just updated my answer/fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y5yBg/2/embedded/result/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with CSS only with relative easing and use a div with absolute positioning to unobtrusive act as the body.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/Hc7UW/3/

```
 #body {
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
a.one:hover ~ #body {
    background: blue;
}
a.two:hover ~ #body {
    background: red;
}
a.three:hover ~ #body {
    background: yellow;
}
```

You can find out more info [here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/)

**EDITED** - *jQuery version also*

The way to select a parent, ie *body* you would need to use jQuery. It can be very easy to apply. The way i would do it, so then i don't have to create a lot of classes etc, is by giving the `a` an `id` that is the name color. Then I would use that as the identifier for the color.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/Hc7UW/5/

```
$('a').hover(function(){
      $('body').css('background', this.id);
}, function(){
      $('body').css('background', '#ccc');
});
```

Comment: Nice trick. BTW, `position: fixed` wouldn't be a better choice? http://jsfiddle.net/Hc7UW/4/

Comment: You should post the HTML and remark that for this to work the a elements must be siblings ahead of body. People that don't know how ~ works may have a hard time figuring why it doesn't work for them. Nice trick anyway !!

Comment: Thanks, i will go for this option, but just one question: 

Is there any way to make the **a and the ~** work inside the **#body** div?

Comment: @YasserLima not in CSS alone. But if carefully planed it can be done with only 4 lines of jQuery and it will apply to all links. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to adapt the answer found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681767/link-animated-color-changing-in-jquery) to suit your needs. You can replace the `$(this)` with the actual selector you want to use (presumably `$('body')`). Just keep in mind that you'll need an additional library (either jQuery UI or the jQuery color plugin) on top of the regular jQuery library.

Comment: Or instead of jQuery UI, the jQuery Color plugin could be used: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Comment: @biziclop I suppose I should have mentioned that too. I edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using jQuery + CSS3 transitions:

http://jsfiddle.net/r3wCE/

jQuery:

```
$b = $('body');
$('a').mouseover(function(){  $b.toggleClass('red', true  );  })
      .mouseout( function(){  $b.toggleClass('red', false );  });
```

CSS:

```
body {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s;
       -moz-transition: background-color 2s;
         -o-transition: background-color 2s;
            transition: background-color 2s;
    background-color: white;
}
body.red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: no need for the true/false switch since mouseover and mouseout only fire once per transition.  `$('a').on("mouseover mouseout", function(){ $b.toggleClass('red');});`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is much jquery oriented. Meaning you wont have to do much in css.

So you can do stuff like generate different colors and append them right away without having to re-configuring css style sheet.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/y5yBg/2/

Code

```
bg=$(document.body);
color=['orange','rgb(42, 212, 255)','rgb(219, 255, 74)'];

$('li').each(function(e){
    $(this).click(function(){
    bg.css('background-color',color[e]);
    });
});
```