# Is it possible to add a jQuery fadeIn function to a css change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was just wondering if it is possible to cause the css background change that I use jQuery to perform can be enhanced with a fadeIn function. I know this can be accomplished using hidden divs, but I would prefer to use 1 div and fadeIn the image from CSS. Here is the working script with no fade.

```
jQuery('nav .home a').mouseover(function()
  {
    jQuery('.viewport').addClass('viewporthome');
  });
jQuery('nav .home a').mouseout(function()
  {
    jQuery('.viewport').removeClass('viewporthome');
  });
```

I tried nesting a `jQuery(jQuery('.viewport').addClass('viewporthome')).fadeIn(1000);` to no avail. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: A jsFiddle would help illustrate your issue, it is hard to know exactly what you are after.

Comment: I am not following...What do you mean by "enhanced"? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Here's a duplicate of what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894734/fade-a-class-in

Comment: I believe OP is trying to essentially fade in a class.

Comment: Do you mean that adding and removing this class adds and removes a background image?  And you would like to have that background image transition fade rather than instant?

Comment: currently the css adds a background to an empty div displaying the image. I would just like to make it so the image fades in gradually instead in appearing instantly like it does now.

Comment: @Dom you got it with the fade, want to post an answer so I can credit ya?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just chain the events.  To fade the `div` in, do the following:

```
jQuery('nav .home a').mouseover(function(){
    jQuery('.viewport').hide().addClass('viewporthome').fadeIn(500);
  });
```

To get the same effect on `mouseout`, use a callback function:

```
jQuery('nav .home a').mouseout(function(){
    jQuery('.viewport').fadeOut(500, function(){ 
        //this is the callback function and runs after div fades out
        $(this).removeClass('viewporthome');
     });
  });
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/Q4wK5/

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI (jqueryui.com) provides that as an extension.  Other than that you would need to apply the styles and animate them.

edit:

you can't fade content separately from background, but you can use img tags to fake the background and fade them:

CSS:

```
#img1.over { opacity: 1; }
#img1.out { opacity: 0; }
#img2.over { opacity: 0; }
#img2.out { opacity: 1; }

.bgndimg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="outer">
       <img id="img1" class="bgndimg out" src="http://i.imgur.com/3KZlvif.jpg?1"></img>
       <img id="img2" class="bgndimg out" src="http://i.imgur.com/LCjgi.jpg"></img>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    $('#outer').hover(function() {
       $('#img1,#img2').toggleClass('over',[15000]).toggleClass('out',[15000]);
     });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9eJVS/1/

Comment: Can you elaborate on which part of jquery UI would be applicable?

Comment: see the doc for [.addClass](http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/addClass/)  you use jQuery('.viewport').addClass('viewporthome',[duration in ms]); jquery ui adds an explicit element style and animates the change

Comment: From the docs:  "Not all styles can be animated. For example, there is no way to animate a background image. Any styles that cannot be animated will be changed at the end of the animation."

Comment: I should learn to read the questions better.  If you want to change the style of the background separately from the content it needs to be a separate selectable element.