# Javascript/JQuery background Image fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

Hello wizards of stackoverflow! I've literally just started using JQuery today and I'm stuck. I need the background image to fadeIn onload. You can ignore the basepath function It's just what i use so I don't ever need to type full paths to images.

Anyway Its simply not working doesn't load or change the background at all. Oddly enough I get no errors in firefox firebug/web developer Pretty lost with JQuery right now.

```
var bodyElement = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
var backgroundSource = $(bodyElement[0]).css("backgroundImage");
var parentDirectory = basepath(backgroundSource);
var IMG = parentDirectory + "/jurasic_bg.jpg";




window.onload = function(){fadeBG();};





function basepath(elementObject){
var elementObject = elementObject.replace(/^url|[\(\)"]/g, '');
var elementPathArray = elementObject.split("/");
var elementPathArrayLength = elementPathArray.length - 1;

for (var counter = 0; counter < elementPathArrayLength; counter++)
    {
        if (counter == 0)
        {
            pathBuilder = elementPathArray[counter];
        }

        else

        var pathBuilder = pathBuilder + "/" + elementPathArray[counter];

    }

        return pathBuilder;
}


function fadeBG(){
    $('body').fadeIn('slow', function()
        {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(', IMG,')');
        });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't animate the background image of the body so far as I'm aware.

What you can do though is make two divs that take up the entire window. I don't think earlier versions of IE support the CSS (`cover`) to do it this way but here's what you can do.

```
<div class='bg none'></div>
<div class='bg one'></div>

div.bg{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-size: cover;
}

div.one{
    background-image: url('path');
    display: none;
}
```

You mentioned jQuery so this is how that would work:  You need to use the document ready event  to trigger your animation.  You may need to `delay` for so long to get your desired effect, but this should get you headed in the right direction.  Oh, and don't forget to include the jQuery library in your HTML before your own script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.one').fadeIn();
    $('div.none').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: This works great actually! However it fades in the child elements too. So instead of giving it the appearance of a background fade looks like the whole page fades in. This is because i had to wrap the fadeIn div around the others to make it full size and not squished on the top or bottom. Any suggestions for this? BTW thanks so much guys both answers are very helpful.

Comment: Ok never mind div problem solved. style for the div must be set top: 0px; left: 0px;

Comment: as well as a fixed or absolute postion. and z-index to position the div behind others.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can fade-in the background of an element separately from its content.

You could make a separate element to hold the background and fade that in, as suggested in [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17074224/is-it-possible-to-add-a-jquery-fadein-function-to-a-css-change/17074266#17074266)

Or you could make the background a .gif that fades in.