# jQuery hover animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-hover

I want to appy a hover effect to div boxes, may be up to 60 boxes on a page. It should be quite equal to the css hover effect but I want to apply a fade effect to the hover color. E.g. I have light green as background color and dark green as hover background color, then it should fade from the one to the other side.

I played a bit around with jQuery but could get the result that I wanted:

```
    $(".box").hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#68BFEF" }, 1000);
    },function() {
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#68BFEF" }, 500);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [decent color plug-in](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color). See [jQuery animate backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor) for more information.

Also, your original code is not really going to do anything, as you want it to animate to another colour afterwards.

```
$(".box").each( function () {
  $(this).data('baseColor',$(this).css('color'));
  $(this).hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#68BFEF" }, 1000);
  },function() {
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: $(this).data('baseColor') }, 500);
  });
});
```

EDIT: see http://jsfiddle.net/eHXNq/2/ for example.

Comment: this. +1 for the link to an appropriate solution

Comment: when I hover the box I get another bgcolor just like expected but when I leave the box the color should fade back to its default and that is nor working...

Comment: Can you post some HTML/CSS? Maybe in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I have found an example that describes exactly what I need http://www.drweb.de/magazin/wp-content/uploads/jquerymenue.html

Comment: thanks for your help, since the boxes can have different colors is there a way to get the current color with jQuery or do I have to apply a color attribute to each box to retrieve it via a selector in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with jQuery, but it looks like just a copy-and-paste mistake, since you have the same color in both `.animate()`s

Comment: jQuery can not do color transitioning by default, and this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not using the `hover` function like you should. the second function is used when the user leave the box so your should return to the original color.

White for example:

```
  $(".box").hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#68BFEF" }, 1000);
    },function() {
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF" }, 500);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".box").hover(
  function () {
 // this is mouseover
  }, 
  function () {
//  this is mouse out
  }
);
```

see example here

http://jsfiddle.net/krRse/

Answer (score 0):

review this code, I think this might help you!!!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  ul { margin-left:20px; color:blue; }
  li { cursor:default; }
  span { color:red; }
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>Bread</li>
    <li class='fade'>Chips</li>

    <li class='fade'>Socks</li>
  </ul>
<script>
$("li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find("span:last").remove();
  }
);



//li with fade class
$("li.fade").hover(function(){$(this).fadeOut(100);$(this).fadeIn(500);});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

take a look at this link too,
http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score -1):

60 boxes? Please use event delegation, or live.

Comment: thinking this should be a comment, as it doesn't really answer the question.  i do agree though.  .delegate() is a beautiful thing.

Comment: @RageZ, its not about catching them all, but the proliferation of events in the dom.  you don't want 120 events hanging around that all do the same thing when 2 delegated events could accomplish the same thing.