# Menu Color Fade on Hover with Jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, fade

One of the members of this community was kind of enough to produce some Jquery code that in effect, fades in a color on rollover and fades it out on rollOut. For convenience, I've included the JSFiddle link here. The main functionality works well. However, when I hover on and off a button rapidly, there appears to be a delayed response that ends up with the hover state becoming dormant even though the mouse is over the button. I'm very close to what I'm looking for and the support of this community has been most appreciated!

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RV6fE/3/

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Set the anchor link opacity to 0 and begin hover function
    $("#menu-sample-menu li a").hover(function () {

        //Fade to an opacity of 1 at a speed of 200ms
        $(this).fadeOut(0).addClass('hover').fadeIn(300);

        //On mouse-off
    }, function () {

        //Fade to an opacity of 0 at a speed of 100ms
        $(this).fadeOut(300)
            .queue(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hover').fadeIn(0).dequeue()
        });

    });
});
```

HTML

```
<nav id="access">
    <ul id="menu-sample-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-198" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-198"><a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/health-care-professional/">Health Care Professional</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-197" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-197"><a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/web-designer/">Web Designer</a>

            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-199" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-199"><a href="http://www.threecell.com/demo/category/construction-worker/">Construction Worker</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Style

```
#access {
    padding:0 20px;
    background:#111;
    box-shadow:0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

#access ul {
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:600;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#access li {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#access ul li:first-child {
    padding-left:0;
}

#access a {
    display:block;
    padding:15px 24px;
    color:#f0f0f0;
    text-decoration:none;

}

#menu-sample-menu li {
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #777;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
}

#menu-sample-menu li a.hover {
    background: orange;
}


#access li.current_page_item > a,
#access li.current-menu-item > a {
    background: orange;
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#access a span {
    color:#999;
    font-size:11px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:1.62em;
    text-transform:none;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help,

T

Comment: Why didn't you use a CSS transition or a color transition using jQuery UI?

Comment: I actually didnt want to use CSS3 because the lack of IE9 support. Regarding the color transition, I'd be interested in seeing how that would work and the differences from the code above

Comment: Ah, ok. I don't really care about IE because I am a Linux fan... :-)

Comment: Life would be made so much easier if there was a perfect universal browser :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to stop currently-running animation, like

```
...
$(this).stop().fadeOut(0).addClass('hover').fadeIn(300);
...
```

and

```
...
$(this).stop().fadeOut(300)
    .queue(function () {
         $(this).removeClass('hover').fadeIn(0).dequeue()
});
....
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RV6fE/7/)

Comment: pls check the fiddle link

Comment: Good, +1. :-) I always like jsfiddles.

Comment: Hi Sudhir, could you suggest a way to implement this code without the link text fading out along with the background. In other words, I'd like for the text to stay while just the background fades in. Thanks for any advice you can provide.

Comment: Hello all...can I anyone suggest how to implement the above code without having the text fade out as well. I'd prefer not to use the background-color property as I may want to include background images in my hover class at some point. Thank you all in advance for any assistance you can provide

Answer (score 2):

You could use this CSS3 feature:

```
#access {
padding:0 20px;
background:#111;
box-shadow:0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

#access ul {
float:left;
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style:none;
font-weight:600;
text-transform:uppercase;
}

#access li {
position:relative;
float:left;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

#access ul li:first-child {
padding-left:0;
}

#access a {
display:block;
padding:15px 24px;
color:#f0f0f0;
text-decoration:none;

}

#menu-sample-menu li {
color: black;
text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #777;
background-color: green;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease; /* CSS3 feature for your background-color transition */
-moz-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
-o-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
padding: 0 12px 0 12px;
}

#menu-sample-menu li:hover {
background: orange;
}


#access li.current_page_item > a,
#access li.current-menu-item > a {
background: orange;
color: white;
text-decoration:none;
}

#access a span {
color:#999;
font-size:11px;
font-style:italic;
font-weight:normal;
line-height:1.62em;
text-transform:none;
}
```

Instead of JQuery. Here is the result you probably want: http://jsfiddle.net/RV6fE/12/

Comment: Thank you for the css3 substitute. I wanted to go with Jquery so that it would be supported in Ie9.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the element to immediately stop what it's doing before you start animating anything.

```
    $("#menu-sample-menu li a").hover(function () {

        //Fade to an opacity of 1 at a speed of 200ms
        $(this).stop().fadeOut(0).addClass('hover').fadeIn(300);

        //On mouse-off
    }, function () {

        //Fade to an opacity of 0 at a speed of 100ms
        $(this).stop().fadeOut(300)
            .queue(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('hover').fadeIn(0).dequeue()
        });

    });
```

Comment: Hi Caleb, could provide some guidance on how to fade out just the background without the text link fading with it? Thx!

Comment: Maybe this could be of some help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612075/jquery-fade-to-color-on-mouse-hover