# Jquery animate background code not working!

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

See I have a jquery code which I thought that it should work but still it's not working! So please can help me out. Th input have original background color `#fff` and I want that on focusing that input the background color should change into `#789` with a fade effect. Here is the code that I have made.

```
$('input.login_reg_input').focus(function () {
   $(this).animate({
     backgroundColor:fadeColor
   }, 250, 'linear', function() { });
});
```

I have search through the stackoverflow and had not found a good solution. So please help me out with this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could actually use CSS 3 to do this too if you're not too bothered about older browsers :-)

Comment: @Jack Billy I've added better alternatives to my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With just the jQuery lib you cannot animate the background color. But you can animate it with the jQuery UI on top of it.

So this works fine

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('input.login_reg_input').focus(function () {
                $(this).animate({
                    'backgroundColor': '#768'
                }, 250, 'linear', function() { });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input class="login_reg_input">click me</input>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Some years later, here are better alternatives:

### Using CSS3

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/15L7zkfL/)

```
input.login_reg_input {
    -ms-transition: background-color 1s;
    -o-transition: background-color 1s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
    transition: background-color 1s;
}

input.login_reg_input:focus {
    background-color: #789;
}
```

---

### Using only jQuery (without jQuery UI)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ystccmex/4/)

```
$('input.login_reg_input').focus(function () {
    var $elem = $(this),
        cnt = 0,
        from = {    // animate from white (reg, green, blue) 255
            r: 255,
            g: 255,
            b: 255
        },
        to = {    // to #778899 (119, 102, 136)
            r: 119,
            g: 102,
            b: 136
        };

    // interpolate "from" color to the "to" color
    $(from).animate(to, {
        duration: 1000,
        step: function(now) {
            // step is invoked for each r, g and b.
            if (++cnt % 3 === 0) {  // I want to process only when the whole triple is interpolated
                $elem.css('background-color',
                          'rgb('
                              + Math.round(this.r) + ',' 
                              + Math.round(this.g) + ','
                              + Math.round(this.b) + ')');
            }
            // confused? Just uncomment line below and you will get the hang of it
            // console.log(now, this);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this paragraph on http://api.jquery.com/animate/:

> All animated properties should be
> animated to a single numeric value,
> except as noted below; most properties
> that are non-numeric cannot be
> animated using basic jQuery
> functionality. (For example, width,
> height, or left can be animated but
> background-color cannot be.) Property
> values are treated as a number of
> pixels unless otherwise specified. The
> units em and % can be specified where
> applicable.

It says that background-color cannot be animated.

Comment: But I have seen this type of in twitter. So I think it might be possible.

Comment: But anyways. Thanks for the advice I will keep record of that.

Comment: You could try to set the background-color after the animation using $(this).css("background-color": "#789");

Comment: Sorry but it is not working for me and the whole code has been crashed none of jquery is working now. Can you suggest something as you are a pro.

Comment: You're right: $(this).css("background-color", "#789"); this should work, I typed a ":" instead of a "," sorry!

Comment: Hey it worked! The link you just gave me helped! Thanks you all guys! Specially Sarah! Thanks a lot!

Comment: $(this).css("background-color", "#789") does not make any background animation, it simply sets the background color. As I said, to make background animation you need the JQuery UI

Comment: I know, it was only my first idea to improvise. But then I found the link I posted above where you can see a demo which is also working with jQueryUI.

Answer (score 1):

From the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) page on jQuery docs:

"All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality. (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be.) Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable."

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor):

It looks as though you will need the jQuery [color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color)

I tried with a test of your code and it works having saved the color plugin locally:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.color.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input class="login_reg_input" type="text" />

    <script>

    $('input.login_reg_input').focus(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({
        backgroundColor:'yellow'
    }, 250, 'linear', function() { });
    });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, which correctly cite the [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) docs, it is possible to animate the `background-color` with either the [color plug-in](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color), or using the [jQuery UI](http://www.jqueryui.com/).

[JS Fiddle usage demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/SprP5/).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't support color animations so you'll need the color plugin or, jQuery UI.

you can use this properties only on the plugins

this is the library
http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.colorBlend.js_6.txt