# How to animate the application of a class to a div

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm wondering how exactly to apply a style to a div, and then remove it slowly via animation? Check out the fiddle link here, this obviously doesn't work, but how would I fix it so it does?

http://jsfiddle.net/csaltyj/PzUdA/

EDIT: sorry, meant fade the background out, not the div itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can simply remove the `.animate()` and replace with:

```
.fadeOut("slow");
```

**EDIT based on your comments that you want to just remove the class and not content:**

Simply include jQueryUI and use [.toggleClass()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/) as is reflected in this ***[working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/dwc8w/)***.

jQuery:

```
$('#press-me').click(function() {

    $('<p>New content.</p>')
        .appendTo('#content-box')
        .addClass('newobj-hilite')
        .toggleClass('newobj-hilite', 2000);

});
```

Comment: This works too. I'm choosing this as the official answer because the code is cleaner. Except I'd use removeClass instead of toggleClass.

Comment: I modified my jsFiddle to be a little playground for you on deciding what values you want to go with on fade in or fade out.  Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
$('#press-me').click(function() {
    $('<p>New content.</p>').appendTo('#content-box').addClass('newobj-hilite').animate({opacity: '0'}, 500);
});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/naveed_ahmad/PzUdA/2/

Also some good stuff to read and learn:

http://webdesignledger.com/tutorials/13-excellent-jquery-animation-techniques

http://designreviver.com/tutorials/20-easy-to-learn-jquery-animation-tutorials/

Comment: PS> Please note that some features won't work on different browsers. Like `opacity` property is not supported in IE. But just wanted to give you an idea. hope that helps.

Comment: That fades out the entire HTML content. I'm just trying to fade out the yellow highlight.

Comment: Basically this question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor

Comment: By adding jQuery UI I've achieved what you wanted. The updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/naveed_ahmad/PzUdA/6/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery UI for that.

```
$('#press-me').click(function() {
    $('<p class="effect">New content.</p>').appendTo('#content-box')
        .addClass('newobj-hilite', 1000, callback)
});

function callback() {
    $(".effect").removeClass("newobj-hilite", 1000);
}
```

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PzUdA/7/).

Comment: Nice! This works, and I feel removeClass() is cleaner than toggleClass(). I did condense your code a bit though: http://jsfiddle.net/csaltyj/PzUdA/10/

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack Note that this condensed code animates only the removal of the class.