# Animating the colour of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery animate backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

I'd like to have a div glow or change colour to indicate to someone that they've received a message. How can I go about animating the background colour of a div in this way?

Comment: Not quite. I forgot to mention that I want this to be cyclical and triggered on page load. However, it shouldn't be hard to adapt the code given.

Comment: Oh noes, flagged by Jeff. I is doomed ;) . More seriously, I did search for this question but using terms such as "glow", "fade" and "transition". It seems I wasn't far off with the word animate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color)
Hope this helps.

Comment: It does. Here's a link with a decent demo (see color animations): http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Effects