# Changing background of a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am using following code to change background color:

```
        $('.posts').animate({height: '100px', backgroundColor: '#0000FF'}, 2000);
        $('.posts a').animate({color: '#00FF00'}, 2000);
```

getting following error on firebug instead of previewing color change in page:

```
Expected color but found 'NaNpx'. Error in parsing value for 'background-color'. Declaration dropped.
Expected color but found '#00FF00px'. Error in parsing value for 'color'. Declaration dropped.
```

What's the error with my code?

Comment: You need plugin read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor/2302005#2302005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `animate` to animate colors without jQuery UI.

> All animated properties should be
>   animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties
>   that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery
>   functionality. (For example, width,
>   height, or left can be animated **but
>   background-color cannot be**.)

and

> The jQuery UI project extends the
>   .animate() method by allowing some
>   non-numeric styles such as **colors to
>   be animated**. The project also includes
>   mechanisms for specifying animations
>   through CSS classes rather than
>   individual attributes.

source: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 2):

jQuery doesn't come with support for animating background-colour by default, but you can use the [Color Plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't animate colors without the color plugin.

http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

You could also use JQuery UI.

> The jQuery UI effects core extends the
>   animate function to be able to animate
>   colors as well.

Comment: jqueryui might do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

To animate colors with query you should use this:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color