# jquery fadeins and fadeouts on CSS properties

Tags: jquery

In this fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/KvwGw/33/ ), when you click the send button, the form fades out, and a new form appears. At the same time, the CSS background color changes.  The code below does that

I am trying to put a fadeout and fadein on the CSS backgrounds (to coincide with the appearance and disappearance of the forms) but can't figure out how to combine fadeins and fadeouts with css elements/properties.

Any suggestions for a newbie would be greatly appreciated.

Note, on my live site, it's background images that are changing but it's happening very abruptly, so I want to put fadeins etc on them

Answer (score 0):

I think the [second answer in this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor) is what you're after. Hope that helps

Comment: I added some information in my OP, namely that on my site I will be changing background images, not color, so I don't think that answer will work. But are you saying that I will definitely need some plugin, that the regular jquery library itself isn't able to do it?