# jquery: simple animate question

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery animate backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

http://johanberntsson.se/dev/fysiosteo/

If you hover the menu, i would like the main menu to fade out its backbgroundcolor to #fff over 1 second. But i cant get it to work. My code:

```
 $('#menu-main-menu').children('li').mouseout(function () {
            $(this).css('background', '#AFFFAF').animate({ 'background' : '#fff' }, 1000);
        });
```

I never use animate(), so ive probably missed something obvious. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for duplicate, you also have to use `background-color` instead of `background`. The color plugin is also included in jQuery UI, so if you're using that, you don't need anything else apart from the fix above.

Comment: Doesn't look like that plugin's page is up anymore.  Can anyone find a more recent link?

Comment: Included jquery UI, but i still dont see an animation. Can you check the source to se if i missed something?

Answer (score 0):

maybe place a function into your animate tag so...

```
$(this).css('background', '#AFFFAF').animate(function() {$(this).css('background', '#FFF')}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet:

```
$("#menu-main-menu").children('li').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#fff" }, 1000);
});
```