# Glow effect with background color using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I add a subtle "glow" effect to a `div` element that will glow all the time/permanently, right after the page load, not just when hovered?

Unfortunately, the client wants me to make this work in IE7+.

Comment: Do you want it to see the glow fade in, or already be glowing when the page loads?

Comment: Do you want it to be animated?

Comment: Definitely could use clarification/example of what "glow" means.

Comment: Sorry folks, you are right. With "glow" I mean animate between 2 color values. It's a simple animation between, say dark green and bright green.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using an animated gif?

Match the solution to the client.

Answer (score 2):

If it should glow permanently all the time, why use Javascript/jQuery at all? This could be done purely using CSS, either using CSS3 box-shadow to simulate glow or using images.

Here's a [CSS3 example](http://www.suburban-glory.com/blog?page=114)

To animate bg-color, check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

Comment: Yes, I know. Unfortunately, the client wants me to make this work in IE7+. So I rather use a JS-based solution. Thx

Comment: It WILL work on IE7+ (using images since IE7 and 8 doesn't really support CSS3). Using jQuery has nothing to do with visual effects. It is the CSS/images that defines the presentation, unless you want to venture into Canvas/SVG territory which is more advanced.

Comment: Oh, ok. Got'ya. I actually mean something else (my fault): What I'd like to do is to animate between to bg-colors, say red and green, to create a glowing effect. Does that make sense?

Comment: Most of the links to the download of the plugin are broken, unfortunately. Isn't there an easier way to animate between two colors in jQuery?

Comment: PAGE NOT FOUND :)