# jQuery fadeTo() for colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

I want an equivalent of `fadeTo()` for colors, instead of opacity.

For example, starting with `backgroundColor = "red"`, how can I gradually move to `backgroundColor = "green"` with jQuery?

Comment: You can use jquery color plugin.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [jQuery UI Color Animation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/).

You may also use CSS3 transitions which I prefer. Not supported in Internet Explorer 9 or older. Will be supported in Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: Try the link. It has a perfect example.

Comment: Ah, beg your pardon. animate() will indeed do the job.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [animate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/)()

```
 $('#yourdiv').animate({ backgroundColor: "green" }, 1000)
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to work. Here is was the documentation says: "All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality. (For example, `width`, `height`, or `left` can be animated but `background-color` cannot be.)"