# animate div background with php

Tags: php, javascript, html, animation

Hello i am trying to animate a div background color this way with php and javascript html.

```
<div background="<?=for($step = 0; $step < 256; $step++)
    echo "rgb($step, $step, $step);"; ?>" /> contents </div>
```

So the code will make change the div from black to white as my example clearly shows.
But it is not working, any ideas?

i want to implement it in my personal website http://www.nickersonweb.com/ buttons

Comment: WOW! Please check the output, and you'll immediately see why it's not working!

Comment: You are getting confused and mixing client side task with server side.

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

Answer (score 4):

Once your page is generated by PHP and sent to the client, your PHP code can no longer change the content on the client side.

That's where client-side code (Javascript) comes in.

To quickly achieve what you're trying to do, have a look at this question: [jQuery animate backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor) , which recommends using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) with the [jquery-color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color). Here's a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MCwxG/

*p.s. I'm sure it's possible to do it with pure javascript, but my js-fu is not accomplished enough to show you how.*

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it with php, it's server side.

But you can do it with the [color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

- Well, you're using `<?=` with a for loop statement, when it should only be used with an expression. You need to change that to `<?php` (or `<?` if your server supports it).
- `<div>`s don't have a `background` attribute. You'd need to modify their `style`.
- You're writing all of the style changes to the page before you're writing the `content`.
- The browser can't even try to render the `<div>` before it's closed with `>`, and all of your styles will be interpreted at once, and only the last one will be visible.