# Animating a background image *bug?* with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I need to animate a background image and am using the code

```
        $('div.holder-inner').css({backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'});

    $('#up').click(function(){
        // alert('!');
        $('div.holder-inner').animate({
            backgroundPosition: '200px 10px'
        });
    });
```

Which fails to work.. it does however work if I amend the backgroundPosition to only contain one value rather than two like so

```
            backgroundPosition: '200px'
```

Tested in firefox 6 and chrome - and produces the same result in both - animates with a single value and does nothing with two values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery standard animate does not work with backgrounds.

Check this thread for explanation: [jQuery animate backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor) and this plugin for solution http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/backgroundPosition/