# .animate in jQuery not working

Tags: jquery

When I hover the button, the background color is not changing.

My jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>  
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".reject").hover(function() {  
        $(this).animate({background: '#000'}, 1000);
    }, function(){  
        $(this).animate({background: '#333'}, 1000);  
    });  
});  
</script>  
<style type="text/css">  
    .reject{padding:10px;font-size:20px;background:#F00;} 
</style>
```

My html:

```
<button  class="reject">Reject</button>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor

Comment: Please format your code so that other people can read it and help you.

Comment: The first comment here is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is [this](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/)
[Check this online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XY4p3/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
//Add this script
<script src="http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/jquery.animate-colors.js"></script>  
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".reject").hover(function() {  
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#000'}, 1000);
    }, function(){  
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#333'}, 1000);  
    });  
});  
</script>  
<style type="text/css">  
    .reject{padding:10px;font-size:20px;background:#F00;} 
</style>
```

**HTML code**

```
<button  class="reject">Reject</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JSfiddle with it working: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2z7Yq/)

You have to include jQuery UI and then use the following jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".reject").hover(function() {  
        // Stop the previous animation (if any) and then animate
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#000'}, 1000);
    }, function(){  
        // Stop the previous animation (if any) and then animate
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor: '#FFF'}, 1000);  
    });  
});
```

Your code was fine, You just have to include jQuery UI. But best to also use the stop function.