# CSS background fade using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background-color

I'm trying to figure out how to just fade in the css background color of my site. However, i'm just getting background images with divs or tags in order to fade them. No examples of just a css background color fade in.

```
 <style type="text/css">
 body {
    background-color: #F00;
 }
 </style>
```

Any help would be great in figuring this simple problem out.

David

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor this may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't animate colors directly with jQuery, however plugins exist to help you out - http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/ for example

Answer (score 1):

There are several plug-ins available that easily accomplish this functionality:

[**jQuery Color Plugin**](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color)

**[jQueryUI Color Animations:](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/ColorAnimations)**

**[Bitstorm Color Animation](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/)**

**Usage for nearly all of them:**

```
$('body').animate({ backgroundColor: "White" }, 'slow');


$(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "black" }, 1000);
```

Comment: do you happen to have the url to the javascript since the site is down it seems?

Comment: @Rionmonster The plugins site is currently unavailable.

Comment: Here is a tutorial that might include the plugin within the download : http://desizntech.info/2009/06/playing-with-jquery-color-plugin-and-color-animation/