# jquery fading in background color property on hover?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I've got a small piece of code that isn't working, take a look:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#mainmenu li:hover').css({backgroundColor:''});
    $('ul#mainmenu li').hover(function() {
        $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#2E8AE5'}, slow);
    });
});
```

It's meant to:

1) unset the CSS property `background-color` from a list item with the pseudo-class `:hover` in the unordered list with an id of mainmenu (this is so those without Javascript enabled can still experience a similar effect to what I'm trying to achieve with jQuery)

2) When the same list item is then hovered over, it should animate in the background-color on said list item.

But it doesn't. Instead, the first task isn't even completed, let alone animating in the background on hover. It's worth noting that I have triple checked my elements (I even copied them and pasted them into the script to make sure).

And I am using jQuery UI - which I understand can perform such tasks involving animating certain CSS properties. Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor) ... use the color plugin

http://jsfiddle.net/Mb6Nd/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var lis = $('#mainmenu > li');
    $(lis).hover(
        function() {
            $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#2E8AE5'}, 'slow');
        },
        function(){
            $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#cecece'}, 'fast');
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: That works great, except my starting color is transparent, and this doesn't work with a transparent starting color, plus it's affecting child elements (a submenu) - so really, this isn't quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Changing your target id to #mainmenu > li will make it affect only the parent level li and not the child li.  Also try backgroundColor: 'transparent !important'

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $lis=$('#mainmenu > li');
    $lis.css({backgroundColor:'transparent !important'});
    $lis.hover(function() {
       $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#2E8AE5'}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

It should be 'background-color'. Not backgroundColor. i.e.

```
$(this).animate({'background-color':'#2E8AE5'}, "slow");
```

---

The parameter for speed should be a string or a number. For example: "slow" or 10000 (millisecs).

ex:

```
$(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#2E8AE5'}, "slow");
```

or

```
$(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#2E8AE5'}, 1000); // in millisecs
```

Comment: Argh, it's a late night - I should've picked that up, but it doesn't fix my problem however.

Comment: `backgroundColor` is a valid CSS property in jQuery, as demonstrated by Tim's answer, also, this doesn't fix my problem, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

does this work?:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $lis=$('#mainmenu li');
    $lis.css({backgroundColor:'#aaa'});
    $lis.hover(function() {
       $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#2E8AE5'}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually, I just retried it with the first background color set to #AAA instead of blank and it worked!!! :D But is there any way I can set `background-color` to nothing initially because having to set it at a preset color ruins how it looks before a mouse rollover? Cheers.

Comment: Also, it's affecting a child menu inside this menu as well. Is there any way to apply the animation to only that particular element, instead of the children elements inheriting it?

Comment: @Antilogical13 You can use `background-color:inherit;`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the best solution for fading in background color, forecolor and border color use plugins like  [color animation jQuery plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/),

Use :

<\script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/jquery.animate-colors.js">

*(Remove the back slash)*.

and after enter the before codes. like.

`$('#demodiv').animate({backgroundColor: '#400101'});`

More reference [click here](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/)