# Scroll effects when scroll position is not constant

Tags: javascript, scroll, themes, tumblr, effects

I'm currently in the process of making a tumblr theme, and I wanted to implement something like this: [jquery change background color user scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755887/jquery-change-background-color-user-scroll) 
for it. My Idea is that when you scroll onto a "image post" the background auto-dims to be a dark gray so you can see the content better, but when you get out of the photo post it goes back to the regular user set color. The only problem is that in the example I linked, it relies on the user scrolling to a certain point on the page, when obviously due to the nature of tumblr, that scroll position isn't constant. Any ideas?

Comment: mouse hoover, mouse click event

Comment: Which of those four examples are you using?

Comment: i'm using the first one. so i just need to figure out something to replace for scroll position

Comment: Are you talking about a single page Tumblr theme with just 1 column full of images? Maybe got an example link?

Comment: I sadly have not seen another example of this. But yeah it would be just a column of posts. The idea was that on scrolling past an image the whole background would dim without any further input, but I'm thinking it might not work anyways. Making it so that the background would dim anytime a photo post was onscreen would mean that it would also hide any other content would hide, even if that's the content whoever is reading is currently interacting with.

Comment: Do you want it to dim the moment the photo is partially in-view or when it's completely in-view? Do you want it to go back to normal the moment the photo becomes partially out of view or when it's totally out of view? Do you only want it to happen when the photo is center screen or anytime it's on screen? And what would you want to have happen when there are photos back to back or someone scrolls quickly?