# Can't animate header with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

So I've been looking far and wide for ways to animate my header to change background color when I scroll further then 550px.

Here is the code:

```
$(function(){
$('header').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
var $header = $('header');
if ($('body').scrollTop() > 550) {
    if ($header.data('size') == 'big') {
        $header.data('size','small').stop().animate({
            'background','#444349'
            }, 'slow');
    }
} else {
    if ($header.data('size') == 'small') {
        $header.data('size','big').stop().animate({
            'background','transparent'
        }, 'slow');
    }  
}
});
```

Comment: You need to animate `backgroundColor` and not `background`, using jQueryUI, but I would be surprised if `transparent` is a numeric color value it can animate to. What is your default/page background color? (animate to that)

Comment: By default, jQuery doesn't support color animation, use a specific plugin for that or better toggle a class and use CSS transition or even better you could target the data attribute specific value of header and set background color to that, still using some CSS transition. **As a side note**, you should use `$(window).scrollTop()` to support all browsers

Comment: possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755887/jquery-change-background-color-user-scroll . With different classes you can animate with css.

Comment: you need to animate the opacity of the `backgroundColor` using the `rgba(r, g, b, a)` syntax, jQuery supports those as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use CSS to animate the header?

CSS:

```css
header {
    background: transparent;
    transition: background .6s; /* 'slow' is 600ms */
}

header.foobar {
    background: #444349;
}
```

JavaScript:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($('body').scrollTop() > 550){
        $('header').addClass('foobar');
    }else{
        $('header').removeClass('foobar');
    }
});
```

Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/obhLxrfz/1/).

Comment: Thanks so much! I am still a noob at jQuery and JavaScript.