# How can I change the background colour of my menu when i scroll down?

Tags: html, css

I'm a pure student's beginner, right now I'm trying to create an adaptive menu for my project, but I need to change the color of my background because white on white is a little bit problematic.

What I tried is to create a script in order to add a class 'scroll' to my 'nav' when I'm scrolling down, and removed it when I'm going back to the top.

But as I said I'm a beginner, and it seems I did something wrong with either my script or my CSS.

Can you help me to understand how where I did something wrong?

Thanks for the help !

PS: Sorry for my english I did my best.

`` `https://codepen.io/Raz7/pen/zYKoJzY` ``

it's completly messed up, probably due to all the image I put in.

Comment: There is no JS - that you are talking about ... in your codepen.

Comment: Could you use jQuery? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755887

Answer (score 1):

In your script tag you are using a JQuery Selector "$" but you did not add the JQuery library.

To keep things simple I will use the built-in querySelector from the document object and Vanilla Javascript.

The following code will do what you want:

```
let timeout;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {

    // If there's a timer, cancel it
    if (timeout) {
        window.cancelAnimationFrame(timeout);
    }

    // Setup the new requestAnimationFrame()
    timeout = window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {

        // Run our scroll functions
        let nav = document.querySelector('nav');

        if (document.querySelector('header').getBoundingClientRect().top !== 0) {
            nav.classList.add('scroll');
        } else {
            nav.classList.remove('scroll');
        }      
    });
}, false);
```

To actually know what the distance to the top is you need a point of reference, in this script I used the header element as a point of reference since the header is relative to the body tag. If the header distance to top is not 0 then add the scroll class to the nav element else remove it. You can see also a timeout and requestAnimationFrame, this helps de-bouncing the scroll event.

Instead of using the JQuery Library, if you are a beginner I suggest learning about Vanilla Javascript and the DOM.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Comment: Thank you so much! 

Indeed it works and it's easy to understand as you type it. I didn't knew about the vanilla Javascript so thanks for your link i will go teach myself about this tonight.