# Animating the background color of a page automatically when a page loads

Tags: jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery animate backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

Is it possible to animate/transition the background-color of a certain element automatically when the page loads?

I have a page with data like this:

```
<ul>
    <li> Some stuff</li>
    <li> Some other stuff</li>
    <li class="unread"> Some more stuff</li>
</ul>
```

For elements with the .unread class I want the  background image to start off as a light yellow color and then have it fade into the regular page background-color (which is white in this case) Think of a new PM or notification on facebook, that is the effect I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the CSS property `transition`;

**HTML**

```
<div class="transition"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.transition {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 1s linear;
}
div.animated {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.transition').addClass('animated');
});
```

See [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uhATT/).

Reference: http://iamchenghan.wordpress.com/2010/05/30/css3-color-animation/

Comment: Using this would mean that the background changes when a user hovers or clicks on an element. I am trying to change the bg color as soon as the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery [Color Plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/color) on the page.

```
$(function() {
    $(".unread").animate({ backgroundColor: "[hex-here]" }, "slow");
});
```

Where [hex-here] is your page background color.

Comment: "most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used." http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I've actually tried this code but it doesn't work. I set .unread background-color to #999 via CSS and then changed [hex-here] to #fff. When the page loads elements with the unread class has a #ccc background. Nothing changes.


EDIT: What stefan said ^

Comment: @Stefan - Thanks. I have included reference to color plugin.

Comment: Anyway to accomplish this without any additional plugins? I am actually trying to go a CSS only route, but will settle on using jQuery if absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Xecure are you animating through greys 999 -> CCC?

Comment: oops sorry what i meant to write was that my bg color is #999 and then tried to change the bg color to #fff. Honestly I haven't picked the color yet. I was going to play around with it until it looked right. But what do you suggest?

Comment: @Xecure Grays are much more linear, so moving from a to b will look much nicer if it's grey. I'd say it's impossible to animate in CSS alone.