# jQuery + CSS. The fastest way to implement the style to numerous elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance

I have a handmade responsive jQuery grid, elements in this grid are DIV's with `float:left`.

Their widths and number in a row are calculating on their container width changes. For example if container width 500px, than it can keep 4 elements in a row, elements width calculated accordinaly as 25%, if container width changes to 400, it can keep only 3 in a row with width 33%.

The calculation is not important, the question is what is the fastest way to change container's elements style? Now I do straitforward

```
$('.container .element').css({width:'25%'});
```

As I understand jQuery iterates each element and changes it's style. But what if I could dynamicly create a style:

```
.container.foo .element {width:25%;}
```

And just add `.foo` class to my container, than I guess this operation would be forced by browser, and it could be much faster.

Is it? Is it possible?

Comment: _"Is it possible?"_ Yes. _"could be much faster"_ Tried benchmarking both options ?

Comment: Consider taking a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720320/how-to-dynamically-create-css-class-in-javascript-and-apply#answer-1720483

Comment: If there is a way to do it with jQuery, there's always a faster way doing it without jQuery. Really, just go for the straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do it is to :

1. Create the classes in your css. Every style you need.
2. Add or remove classes with jQuery. `addClass` / `removeClass`

So yes, the second option is faster, cleaner and reusable. It's about [50% faster.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246242/which-is-faster-modifying-css-property-or-adding-class-in-jquery)

Comment: I think OP is talking about creating also the class dynamically, not just applying an existing one.

Comment: Maybe, still if it's a % you should be able to use CSS. It might become very messy to do it in jQuery. You can swap `.row25` to `.row33`, etc.

Comment: At first I thought to create a dynamic classes, but predefined classes should be faster, and I think 10 classes up to 10 elements in a row per 10% width is enough. Thank you.