# Setting a .delay().animate() method on a form field with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, delay

I have a button only my page that will jump the user to a contact form below and I want to highlight the first field in the form briefly then have it animate back to the preset focus background color. Seems that using the `.css()` method doesn't allow delays and also seems that `.animate()` doesn't work on changing attributes of a form field. Any tips?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#class_sign_up_btn, #work_with_brian_btn').click(function() {
        $('#name').focus();
        $('#name').css('background','#E3BD00').delay(500).animate( {'background':'grey'}, 300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for animation, might want to read this: [jQuery animate backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

```
$('#class_sign_up_btn, #work_with_brian_btn').click(function() {
 $('#name').focus();
    $('#name').css('background','#E3BD00');

    setTimeout(function() {  
        $('#name').css( {'background':'grey'});
    }, 500);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is jQuery needs an extension in order to be able to support animations of color properties, including background-color.

You have a couple options. You can grab the [jQuery Color plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/color) or the [jQuery UI core](http://jqueryui.com/download). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a setTimeout.  Make sure to store a ref to the timeout so you can clear it if the buttons are clicked again.

`$(document).ready(function() {
    var timeout;

```
$('#class_sign_up_btn, #work_with_brian_btn').click(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $('#name').focus();
    $('#name').css('background','#E3BD00');
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#name').animate({'background': 'grey'}, 300);
    }, 500);
});
```

});

`

Comment: Turns out JQuery UI has this build in as a [.highlight() method](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight). It works for exactly what I was trying to do — focus on a field in a form and draw extra attention to it briefly. Good to know how to do this with native JS though using the .setTimout() method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `setTimeout()` you can use animate like this:

```
  let orange_h1 = $(".orange_h1");
  orange_h1.animate({
      bottom: "0px",
      height: "50px",
    },
    8000
  );
```