# jQuery animate background-color on input button not working

Tags: jquery, html, animation, css, jquery-animate

I have absolutely no idea why the background color isn't changing and I've spent far too much time on it already:

```
<input type="button" class="front-consultation-btn" value="Get A Free Consultation">

<script>
    $('.front-consultation-btn').animate({ backgroundColor: '#FF0000', width: 400 }, 500);
</script>
```

Why does this ONLY change the width property?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor

Answer (score 2):

This is because jQuery doesn't support animating colors by default, jQueryUI adds this functionality: http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

Comment: [Here](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) is something fairly simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use CSS3?

```css
.yourelement {
    background: #fff;
}

.yourelement:focus, .yourelement:hover {  
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s linear;   
    background: #ccc;   
}
```

Comment: I'd say because U can't add a callback to it?