# how to change div background-color with fadeIn/Out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, background-color, fadeout

How to change div background-color with fadeIn/Out,I only want to fade background color,not background image,Please give me some useful code or solution

Comment: Do you want to animate the background color? Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor

Comment: Demo: http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/

Answer (score 1):

Although [only supported by modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions) you might also consider using [CSS transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp) to achieve the same effect

HTML

```
<div class='foobar'></div>
```

CSS

```
.foobar {
    /* transition properties */
    transition: background-color 2s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 2s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 2s;
    -o-transition: background-color 2s;

    /* basic styling & initial background-color */
    background-color:maroon;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

/* Change background color on mouse over */
.foobar:hover {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Working example here, http://jsfiddle.net/eRW57/14/

Answer (score 1):

with this you can fadeout all div's with id #my-background

```
var $div = $('#my-background');
  $div.each(function blank(){
  $(this).animate({'backgroundColor': '#fff'},2000);
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, but this works as fade in, how to do fade out for the same thing.

Comment: (continuing from the previous comment) I mean it fades in and disappears all of a sudden, can we reverse the effect, i.e appears all of a sudden and then fades out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fade just the background (color or otherwise) of an element using jQuery's fadeIn/fadeOut.

What you can do is place an additional layer (DIV, etc) with your background color and fade in/out on that.

Instead of something like this:

```
<div id="my-background"></div>
```

Use this structure:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="my-background"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container
{
 position:relative;
 width:200px;
 height:100px;
 background-image:url(my-background-image.jpg);
}
#my-background
{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 background-color:blue;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:99;
}
```

Then use jQuery's fadeIn/fadeOut methods

JS

```
jQuery("#my-background").fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").toggle(function(){
    $("body").css("background-color","green");},
    function(){
    $("body").css("background-color","red");},
    function(){
    $("body").css("background-color","yellow");}
  );
});
</script>
```

try it.. that should work fine