# jQuery Hover Effect for NavBar not working?

Tags: jquery, html, navigation, hover, navbar

For some reason, I just can't get the hover effect to work
HTML:

```
<div id="navbarcontainer">
    <ul>
        <li id="left" class="current">
            <a id="current">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dependant1">
            <a id="dependant1">Services</a></li>
        <li id="right" class="dependant2">
            <a id="dependant2">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbarcontainer {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 50px;
background: #01216D;
}

#navbarcontainer ul {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#navbarcontainer li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -o-transition: .5s;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
    /* Firefox 4 */
    /* Opera */
    /* Safari and Chrome */
}

    #navbarcontainer ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 50px;
        width: 100px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: Calibri;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

#left {
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#right {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.current {
    background: #fff;
}

#current {
    color: #01216D;
font-weight: bold;
}

#dependant1, #dependant2 {
   color: #fff;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#dependant1").hover(function () {
    $('.dependant1').stop().animate({background: '#fff' }, "slow");
    $('#dependant1').stop().animate({color: '#01216D', 'font-weight': 'bold'}, "slow");
}, function () {
    $('.dependant1').stop().animate({ background: 'none' }, "slow");
    $('#dependant1').stop().animate({color: '#fff', 'font-weight': 'normal'}, "slow");
});
```

I feel like it has something to do with the jQuery, but I have it in the document.load, so I don't understand why it isn't working.

Comment: The jQuery code shown was just a test to try the hover effect, so I know it would only work on one link

Comment: you cannot animate `color` and `background` with just jQuery, use jQuery UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include after `jQuery` the `jQuery UI Library` :

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/amarog/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
$("#navbarcontainer li").hover(function () {
    $(this).find('a').stop().animate({ color: '#01216D', backgroundColor: '#fff'}, 800);
}, function () {
    $(this).find('a').stop().animate({ color: '#fff', backgroundColor: '#01216D'}, 800);
 });
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="navbarcontainer">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a>Services</a></li>
      <li><a>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbarcontainer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #01216D;
}
#navbarcontainer ul {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#navbarcontainer li {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-transition: .5s;
    -o-transition: .5s;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    transition: .5s;
}
#navbarcontainer ul li a {
    float:left;
    color:#fff;
    background: #01216D;
    padding:10px 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Calibri;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#current {
    background: #fff !important;
    color: #01216D !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Or another script:

```
$("#navbarcontainer li").on('mouseenter mouseleave',function ( e ) {
  var set = e.type=='mouseenter' ? {c:"#01216D", bg:"#fff"} : {c:"#fff", bg:"#01216D"} ;
  $('a', this).stop().animate({ color: set.c, backgroundColor: set.bg}, 800);
});
```

Comment: This wouldn't have worked as roXon and vletech explained. Needed additional jQuery files not included in the original download.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your a tag CSS

```
#navbarcontainer ul li a {

        display: block;
        height: 50px;

        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: 50px;
        width: 100px;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: Calibri;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Comment: Did you check out @roXon his/her comment. That is valid.

Comment: Yeah, I'm testing it out now.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to animate the background color and text color which you can't do with jQuery alone. To achieve what you're trying to do above in your description you need to include the color animation plugin which is [available here](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/).

After you have included that you're code should work as expected.

**EDIT**

Please see this [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/SfWAS/) with the plugin included.

```
$('#color').on('click',function(){
    $(this).animate({backgroundColor:'#400101', color:'#fff'}); 
});
```

Comment: I added jQuery UI 1.10.2 and it fixed part of the problem. Just playing around with it now, thank you.

Comment: Sorry yes I forgot to mention it also works with UI. Glad you got it all working now

Comment: Thanks! Thought I was coding something wrong, didn't realize jQeuery needed help haha.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [library to animate color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) with jQuery and you need to animate background-color not background and when fading back to you need to fade back to blue, not none.

This js fiddle shows your demo working: http://jsfiddle.net/Mbppv/

Here is what I've changed your js to:

```
$("#dependant1").hover(function () {
    $('.dependant1').stop().animate({"background-color": '#fff' }, "slow");
    $('#dependant1').stop().animate({color: '#01216D', 'font-weight': 'bold'}, "slow");
}, function () {
    $('.dependant1').stop().animate({"background-color": '#01216D' }, "slow");
    $('#dependant1').stop().animate({color: '#fff', 'font-weight': 'normal'}, "slow");
});
```

Also see this related post on animating colour: [jQuery animate backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

Answer (score 0):

You can add hover effects to elements with the CSS pseudo-class `hover`. Adding this style to your CSS file applied a red background to the `li` on hover:

```
li.dependant1:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xuHjJ/

Comment: I figured I could do it with CSS, but I thought it would be smoother with jQuery. Will run with CSS for now, thanks.

Comment: You can add CSS transition to create an animated effect
http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_transitions.asp

Comment: While jQuery would work, this is probably the simpler (and more feasible) solution. jQuery is better saved for the more complicated stuff. In the end, it's really whatever floats your boat, but I swear by Occam's razor on this one. :)