# Jquery changing background color on hover, keeps flashing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

so I'm currently making a toplist and I'd like to add a little javascript to it. 
I've decided to make a background color fade in when a visitor hovers their mouse over a name.

But the problem is, it keeps flashing in and out, which is quite annoying! - Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var isOn = false;
    if(isOn == false) 
    {
        $('#rank<?= $info['ID']; ?>').hover(function(){
            isOn = true;
            $('#rank<?= $info['ID']; ?>').animate({
                backgroundColor: '#FF0000'
            }); 
        });
    }
    $('#rank<?= $info['ID']; ?>').mouseout(function(){
        isOn = false;
        $('#rank<?= $info['ID']; ?>').animate({
            backgroundColor: 'white'
        });
    });

</script>
```

I want to fade in to a color when a visitor hovers over the area, and change back to a different color when a visitor hovers out of the area.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events

Comment: something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/t84xa/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `hover` shortcut incorrectly. `hover` actually takes *two* functions and binds to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. Your current code is binding to `mouseenter` and `mouseout`, which will cause problems.

What you actually want is this:

```
var isOn = false;
if(isOn == false) 
{
    $('#rank<?= $info['ID']; ?>').hover(function() {
        isOn = true;
        $('#rank<?= $info['ID']; ?>').animate({
            backgroundColor: '#FF0000'
        }); 
    },
    function() {
        isOn = false;
        $('#rank<?= $info['ID']; ?>').animate({
            backgroundColor: 'white'
        });
    });
}
```

You might also want to include some `.stop()` functions so you don't have a problem with your animation queue.

You should never use `mouseover` or `mouseout` because they fire multiple times when you enter or leave an element.  See the demo at the bottom of http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ for an illustrative example.

Comment: Wow, I really do appreciate this! Thank you! But for the sake of me learning, can we just go through the code?

You have added "}, function() {". That means when the .hover function has completed, that will trigger correct? Just being sure mate.

Comment: Yes, the first function is triggered on `mouseenter`, the second function is triggered on `mouseleave`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot animate colors using standard jQuery, you need additional scripts, EG: jQuery UI.

Also searching should  have helped to fix this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2302005/2373138

Comment: Have a look at this external resources ;)

Comment: I meant edit something trivial, b/c I can't remove d/v without an edit

Comment: just so I could up vote you. If I downvote you, I cannot un-downvote b/c of the SO rules (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70853/what-is-the-justification-for-locking-votes) so I need an edit to allow me to up vote you. Feel free to revert the change

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS(3) check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation4)

If you want to use JS, use a mouse-enter and -leave start/stop function.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the latest [Jquery color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color).

From api.jquery.com/animate/

> ...most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used).