# Can't get jquery animate to work

Tags: jquery

I have a validation and depending on if its correct or wrong i want it to animate the textboxes background-color in different colors: Red if its wrong and green if its correct input. I have tried all different combinations but i just cant get it to work.

```
$("#PersonId").animate({background: "#ff2cf0"});

$( "#PersonId" ).animate({
      backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
    }, 1000 );
```

etc etc.. What am i doing wrong? I have implemented the JQuery UI file to my .NET project so i don't think it is anything wrong there.

Comment: Should work so let me ask;: what doesn't work?

Comment: possible dublicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor

Comment: Works same code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HKh6K/1/). What is your problem?

Comment: Please show us some more of your code.  What you have shown us is fine, so that's not your problem.

Comment: Is your element id unique - correct on your page?

Comment: try `console.log(jQuery.Color);` to see, if the plugin is really loaded.

Comment: okej, Jakub the plugin is not realy loaded. How do i load it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to include the [jQuery color animations plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/color/).

```
$( "#PersonId" ).animate({
  backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
}, 'fast');
```

Comment: How do i do that? Ive created a .js file with the code in and ive put it in my content/js folder in my mvc4 project. I have linked it in my layout like this: <script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/js/jQuery.Color.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> is there anything else i need to do?

Comment: download the plugin from the site, you need jquery ui also I believe. make sure to include it AFTER you include jquery otherwise the plugin won't get recognized