# Animate CSS changes after fadeIn?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, fadein

I'm trying to animate a  box's CSS after it has faded in after X seconds (to simulate new, and old) however it doesn't even animate as intended. I also tried `.promise().done(function(){ animate({ ... }) })` after the `fadeIn()` on the end of the `.click()` but that didn't seem to do it either. Is there another way? I've seen it done. :O

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/2QnTj/)

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var box = $('#box');
    box.fadeIn('slow');
    var end = setInterval(function() {
        box.animate({
            backgroundColor: '#EFE9A8',
            borderColor: '#F7B64D',
            color: '#AD771F'
        }, 1200);
        clearInterval(end);
    }, 200);
});
```

### Update:

It seems my *[animation doesn't work at all](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/2QnTj/2/)* actually.

Comment: this might help you, check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor

Comment: @Rjonacci LOL! I _just_ found the same articles! Posting revisions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an animation (or any code for that matter) run after a `fadeIn` you can use the callback parameter:

```
$('#box').fadeIn('slow', function () {
    // code goes here
});
```

Unfortunately however, you are trying to animate colours and this is unsupported in basic jQuery.  So to answer your question (how to queue an animation to run after a fadeIn), use the callback.  But to answer your *implied* question (how to animate colours) you'll need to get the "Color" plugin for jQuery or use jQuery UI which does have support for animating colours.

More information on the `animate()` method here: https://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Oh, that's right, you can do a callback. Silly me. I did figure it out minutes later haha see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sequence an animation after the end of another, you could do something like this:

```
box.fadeIn('slow').delay(200).animate({
                backgroundColor: '#EFE9A8',
                borderColor: '#F7B64D',
                color: '#AD771F'
            }, 1200);
```

Your jsFiddle can not work because it doesn't have the color animation plugin. Anyway, even if I add jQuery UI (which now includes the color animation plugin), I can't make it work with jsfiddle. I think there's an issue with jQuery UI in jsFiddle.

Edit: Try it with jsbin: http://jsbin.com/xadiwuxo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Edit2: in fact jsfiddle works if you use the correct jQuery UI version. I think you need at least jQuery UI 1.9.x. The jsFiddle above uses jQuery 1.x (edge) and therefore is limited to jQuery UI 1.8.9.

Comment: Thanks, I found all this out with a refined search. See my answer.

Comment: Good to know. Please try using `delay` instead of `setInterval`. It's clearer and you can interrupt the effect directly through jQuery calls in case you have a long animation and want to transition directly. setInterval would just screw up this kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

You can include `jQuery UI` in order to make `.animate()` work with color animation.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2QnTj/6/)**

Comment: Thanks, I found all this out haha. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

aminate in jquery does not work for **BackGroundColor**.. so you have to use another color  plugin...

Or very neat and clean way is use the CSS3 transition  property..

add the below css for Box --

```
#box
{
..
..
..

-webkit-transition:all 1s;
-moz-transition:all 1s;
-o-transition:all 1s;
transition:all 1s
}
```

and in jquery set the background color border or whatever u wnt

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    var box = $('#box');
    setTimeout(function(){
        box.css({
        backgroundColor: '#EFE9A8',
        borderColor: '#F7B64D',
        color: '#AD771F'
        });
    },1200);        
});
```

CHECK THE [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2QnTj/9/)

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out minutes later, see my answer below. Haha.

Answer (score 0):

Well silly me, I didn't know you needed a extension to handle some animation properties. Have a look at **[jQuery Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color)** on the GitHub.

*"jQuery Color has faithfully supported animating colors between two hex values since the beginning. Many developers asked for access to the internal functions we had declared to make it all possible. Version 2 now includes an API to create and modify colors, as well as support for RGBA & HSLA colors and animations."* **~jQuery Blog**

This plugin was my savior, and adds all the flexibility I need. **[Here is the revised version of the original code](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/sV4e4/)**.

All I had to do was add the jQuery Color extension, and all was good to go.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color.plus-names-2.1.2.js"></script>
```

*It's best to store the script locally, and use the compressed version, this is for testing purposes on JSFiddle.*