# Using animate to fade an image to a specified color using jquery ui

Tags: jquery

basically I'm trying to have an image fade to a color when the mouse hovers over it and turn back into the image when the mouse leaves. However, right now nothing happens at all. Here is my jquery ui code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tilesetsmall").mouseover(function() {
         $(this).animate({ backgroundColor:'#DEA8E0'},1000);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor:'#FF0000'},1000);
    });       
});
```

.tilesetsmall is the class of an image. I'm using this for the source of jquery ui:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Any help would be awesome and much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Change your `backgroundColor` to `background-color`, then it should works..

As you can read from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), and `backgroundColor` is not the right CSS properties..

```
.animate()
Perform a custom animation of a set of CSS properties
```

**TESTED:**

It seems there is a bug in the jQuery UI Animate backgroundColor, so instead of using that use [jQuery.Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color)..

Check out this working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BCk8Z/2/)... Hope it helps..

Comment: oh... ok I tried it in jsfiddle and it worked but I had no idea why it didn't elsewhere

Comment: yes I just tried it as you suggested... it's still not working

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor

Comment: i literally copypasted his code into mine and changed it for .tilesetsmall but still nothing happens... not sure why