# How change background-color with jquery animation, like a transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a function that changes the background of a div to colors that are within an array. I did the following:

Html:

```
<div class="background">
```

Css:

```
    .background {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: #000;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
    function spectrum() {
        var time = 0;
        var colours = ['green', 'blue', 'red'];
        var hue = colours[time];


        $('.background').animate({
            backgroundColor: hue
        }, {
            duration: 1000,
            complete: function () {
                time += 1;
    spectrum();
            }
        });
    };
```

The problem is that I am unable to use like a recursion, it changes the background once and stops... What am I doing wrong here???

I tried to find a code ready to use, but just find CSS3, and I want to give support for IE8.

Anyone knows a good way to do what i am trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Please refer to this: [jQuery animate backgroundColor][1]`


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry with all colors you can do this:

```
    function  spectrum(){
    var  mcolors = ['green', 'blue', 'red'];
    var time = 500;             
    $.each(mcolors, function(index, value){
    setTimeout( function(){ 
$('.background').css({
    transition: 'background-color 1s ease-in-out',
    "background-color": value
    }); }, time)
    time += 1000;
    });}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('.background').css({
 transition: 'background-color 1s ease-in-out',
 "background-color": "red" });
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that I am unable to use like a recursion, it changes
>   the background once and stops... What am I doing wrong here???

`var time = 0;`

defines `time` as `0` at each call of `spectrum`, resulting in `time += 1;` at `.animation()` `complete` function not being applied at recursive `spectrum` calls.

---

For applying a color animation effect, try utilizing [jQuery Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/)

```js
function spectrum(t) {
 
      var colours = ["green", "blue", "red"];
      var time = t && t < colours.length ? t : 0;
      var hue = colours[time];

      $(".background").animate({
        backgroundColor: hue
      }, {
        easing: "linear",
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function() {
          time += 1;
          // recursively call `spectrum`,
          // with `time` as argument
          spectrum(time);
        }
      });
    };
    spectrum();
```

```css
.background {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color.plus-names-2.1.2.min.js">
</script>
<div class="background"></div>
```

Comment: `jquery`, `jqueryui` loaded , defined ? Tried ie11 ?

Comment: IE11 is ok, but 8 not so much haha

Comment: Have not viewed `jqueryui` source to determine how `color` animations are implemented, if `css` `transitions` utilized. Appear `css` `transition` supported at ie10+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

Comment: @DRX See updated post. Substituted jQuery Color for full jQuery UI. `css` `transition` not appear utilized to color implement effects.