# jquery fade css not working

Tags: jquery, css, fade

I am trying to make the background change colour based on idle / movement.

that works, but i cannot get it to fade using fadeIn.

[JSFiddle - Working example without the fade](http://jsfiddle.net/bluey/5k6mmdmb/)

What is the best solution to fade the backgrounds at the point of

`$("body").css('background-color','#000');`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var idleState = false;
        var idleTimer = null;
        $('*').bind('mousemove click mouseup mousedown keydown keypress keyup submit change mouseenter scroll resize dblclick', function () {
            clearTimeout(idleTimer);
            if (idleState == true) { 

                    $("body").css('background-color','#fff'); 

            }
            idleState = false;
            idleTimer = setTimeout(function () { 

                    $("body").css('background-color','#000');

                idleState = true; }, 2000);
        });
        $("body").trigger("mousemove");
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `animate` instead of `css` to achieve what you want.

```
 $('body').animate({"background-color":"#fff"}, 1000);
```

Comment: @DavidAnderton yep, try running that code on console log. Make sure to change the background-color value to see the results.

Comment: You are right my bad - I had read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor and got the impression it wasn't possible using vanilla animate

Comment: @DavidAnderton no problem man, that post do give a wrong impression. If I have searched that first I could have argued with my post.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS.

```
body {
    transition: background-color 1s;
}
```