# JQUERY - Animated naviagtion background-color

Tags: jquery, animation, background-color

I'm trying to change my navigation background color with an animation but it's not working.

I currently got the following code:

```js
//NAV

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
          $("#posnav").animate({
          backgroundColor: "#aa0000"
        }, 1000 );
        } else {
          $("#posnav").animate({
          backgroundColor: "#transparant"
        }, 1000 );
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: To animate colors you either need the [jQuery Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) or [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/), as of my knowlegde it is not supported in the jQuery core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery animate backgroundColor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

Comment: You got a typo in "navigation" in your title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, jQuery .animate() only works with numeric properties such as *width*, *height*, and *margins*, but NOT colour -- in which case you need a plugin. See: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

You can, however, use the CSS transition property to achieve similar effect.

```
// CSS

#posnav { 
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}
#posnav.scrolled {
    background-color: #aa0000; 
}

// JS:

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
      $('#posnav').addClass('scrolled');
    } else {
      $('#posnav').removeClass('scrolled');
    }
  });
});
```

See https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition for more details.

PS. Note that your CSS code contains a typo. It should be *transparent* (without the poundsign, spelt with an 'e').