# Can't get jQuery mouseenter, mouseleave and click to work

Tags: jquery, mouseenter, mouseleave

What i'm after is when I hover over an element with the ID #work, I want the background to animate into a different color. Hence this code:

```
$("#work").on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(".wrapper").animate( {"background-color": '#EF6C00'});
  })
```

And when the mouse doesn't hover over the element and leaves, i want it to go back to it's original color. Hence this code:

```
$("#work").on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(".wrapper").animate( {"background-color": '#395eb0'});
  })
```

Now to my problem. When i'm trying to tell jQuery that when I click on the element, It should keep the color it's animating to. Which simply doesn't work at all.
Here's the full code:

```
  $("#work").on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(".wrapper").animate( {"background-color": '#EF6C00'});
  })

  $("#work").on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(".wrapper").animate( {"background-color": '#395eb0'});
  })

    $("#work").on('click', function() {
    $(".wrapper").css("background-color", '#EF6C00');
  });
```

Comment: Are you clicking element while animation is still in process?

Comment: Can u give us an HTML snippet so we can make a jdfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need some plugin that has color animation. Try jQuery UI or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

Now what happens with your code:

1. You hover element.
2. Animation starts.
3. You click element.
4. Click event changes color of element.
5. Animation next step occurs an re-draws element with current step color.
6. Animation continues to execute.

So you need to stop animation first.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#work").on('mouseenter', function() {
    $(".wrapper").stop().animate({
      "background-color": '#ef6C00'
    }, 2000);
  })

  $("#work").on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(".wrapper").stop().animate({
      "background-color": '#395eb0'
    }, 2000);
  })

  $("#work").on('click', function() {
    $(".wrapper").stop().css("background-color", '#ef6C00');
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #ef6C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper" id="work"></div>
```