# jquery animate body background color not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the color of the body whenever I scroll, if I use the jquery css() method, everything works but the thing is I want to put some delay on this effect so I need to animate instead but when I use the following code, the color is not animating, what am I missing?

```
$("body").animate({
    backgroundColor: "white !important"
});

// works well with $("body").css("background-color", "white");
```

I don't want to use css transitions.

Comment: Its already solved here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor

Comment: @zer00ne - are you sure about camel case?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Funsella/pen/yLfAG/    try this pen code, it might help you.

Comment: @JaromandaX just tested it does, my bad.