# How to use animate background of an element in single color

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this demo. Is it possible to change the background color of an element using jQuery animate?

```js
$('#change').on('click', function () {
    $('body').animate({background:'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)'}, 300);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="change">Change BG</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery animate backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I offer an alternative? There are lots of jQuery plugins that do this sort of thing but it is massive overkill for what you are doing.

Background, and more specifically `background-color` is animatable with CSS, so I'd recommend using a transition property like this:

https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/GwqMpR

HTML:

```
$("#change").click(function(){
  $("body").addClass("green");
})
```

CSS:

```
body{
  transition: background 1s;
}

body.green{
  background:green;
}
```