# want to fade in and fadeout the background color in webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Javascript Jquery code

want to fade in and fade out the background color on div

```
    $("div").focusin(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","green"),fadein(5000);
    });
    $("div").focusout(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color","white"),fadein(5000);
    });

})
```

HTMl code

```html
<div>
  first name:
  <input type="text" name="" id="" />
  last name:
  <input type="text" name="" id="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery animate backgroundColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190560/jquery-animate-backgroundcolor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you specifically want to do it with jquery, there is an easy css-only method:

```css
input
{
  transition: background-color 5s ease;
  background-color: white;
}
input:focus
{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  first name:
  <input type="text" name="" id="">
  last name:
  <input type="text" name="" id="">
</div>
```